# Else Statement in PHP

Tags: php

I'm learning PHP and wrote a simple translator.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Translator</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="">
<input type="string" name="word">
<input type="submit"> 
</form>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST["word"])) {
 $word = $_POST["word"];
 echo $word . " -> ";

function translate($word){
$dict = array('hello' => 'sawadee khap','thanks' => 'kap khum khap','sorry' => 'mai pen rai');
 foreach ($dict as $en => $th) {
  if ($word == $en) {
   echo $th;
   break;
  }
 }
} 

translate($word);

} else {
 echo "enter a word";
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I display the string 'not in dictionary' when I enter a word that isn't in the array? I'd also appreciate any feedback or suggestions on improving the code.

Comment: let the golf code begin!

Comment: You don't really need a loop for what you're doing. You can just echo the EN to TH translation by doing `$dict[$word]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your function code

```
function translate($word){
$dict = array('hello' => 'sawadee khap','thanks' => 'kap khum khap','sorry' => 'mai pen rai');

if(array_key_exists($word, $dict)){
     echo $dict[$word];
}else{
    echo 'not in dictionary';
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

PHP has a function for this, called `in_array`. You can do something like this :

```
$dict = array('hello' => 'sawadee khap','thanks' => 'kap khum khap','sorry' => 'mai pen rai');
if(!in_array($word, array_keys($dict))){
    echo '"' . $word . '" not found in the dictionary.';
}else{
    echo $dict[$word];
}
```

**Edit: Improved**

```
$dict = array('hello' => 'sawadee khap','thanks' => 'kap khum khap','sorry' => 'mai pen rai');
if(!array_key_exists(strtolower($word), $dict)){
    echo '"' . $word . '" not found in the dictionary.';
}else{
    echo $dict[$word];
}
```

Comment: `} else { echo $dict[$word]; }` would make it complete

Comment: @ReneKorss Thanks. Edited.

Comment: might as well add an `strtolower` on top of that, it would be weird not to match as simple `Hello` (uppercase)

Answer (score 1):

If you return a value from the function when a word is found or falsoe otherwise you can do a logical test on the result to display the alternative error message.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="string" name="word">
    <input type="submit">   
</form>
<?php 
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        if ( isset( $_POST["word"] ) ) {

            $word = $_POST["word"];
            echo $word . " -> ";

            function translate( $word=false ){
                if( $word ){
                    $dict = array('hello' => 'sawadee khap','thanks' => 'kap khum khap','sorry' => 'mai pen rai');
                    foreach ($dict as $en => $th) {
                        if( $word == $en ) {
                            return $th;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            } 

            $result=translate( $word );
            echo $result ? $result : 'Sorry, not found!';

        } else {
            echo "enter a word";
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use array_key_exist :

```
$dict = array('hello' => 'sawadee khap','thanks' => 'kap khum khap','sorry' => 'mai pen rai');
if (array_key_exists($word, $dict)) {
//in dictionary
}else{
//not in dictionary
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="string" name="word">
    <input type="submit">   
</form>

<?php

function translate($word) {
    $dict = array('hello' => 'sawadee khap', 'thanks' => 'kap khum khap', 'sorry' => 'mai pen rai');

    if (array_key_exists($word, $dict)) {
       echo $dict[$word];

    } else {
        echo " not in dictionary";
    }
}

if (isset($_POST["word"])) {
    $word = $_POST["word"];
    echo $word . " -> ";
    translate($word);
} else {
    echo "enter a word";
}
?>
```

Comment: @ReneKorss Because we CAN! :D

Answer (score -1):

Your top if statement is missing a brace.

As to your question, I assume that you are wanting to walk through the dictionary and if the word isn't found to echo it. You could use a flag. Set it to something before the for loop and then when you find the word set it to something else. Then check at the end of the for loop eg:

```
$found = false;
foreach ($dict as $en => $th) {
    if ($word == $en) {
        $found = true'
        echo $th;
        break;
    }
}
if (!$found) echo $word;''
```